# Having Trouble Running Query From Shortcode Using Tribe's Events Plugin

Tags: wp-query, shortcode

I am not getting any results back using this code, even though I am passing in correct values. Can someone please take a look?

```
function webinar_list_shortcode($atts) {
  global $post;
 // Defaults
extract( shortcode_atts ( array (
        'posts' => '5',
        'status' => 'future',
        'eventcat' => ''
    ),
    $atts
));

$options = array(
    'eventDisplay'=>$status,
    'posts_per_page'=>$posts,
    'tax_query'=> array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
            'tag_ID' => $eventcat
        )
    )
);

 // query is made
 $query = new WP_Query( $options );

 // Reset and setup variables
 $output = '';
 $temp_title = '';
 $temp_link = '';
 $temp_ex = '';
 $temp_content = '';
 $temp_thumb = '';
 $temp_id = '';

 // the loop
 if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $temp_id = $post->ID;
    $temp_title = the_title('','',false);
    $temp_link = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $temp_content = get_the_content($post->ID);
    $temp_date = tribe_get_start_date( $post->ID, true, 'l, F j, Y' );
    $temp_speaker = get_field('speaker');
    //$temp_ex = get_the_excerpt();
      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $temp_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(200,200));
      } else {
        $temp_thumb = "";
      }

    // output all findings -
   $output .= "
  <div class='et_pb_row webinar-row clearfix'>
  <div class='et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4'>
   $temp_thumb
  </div>
  <div class='et_pb_column et_pb_column_3_4'>
   <div class='post-$temp_id' id='post-$temp_id'>
              <h3 class='webinar-time'>
                  $temp_date
              </h3><!--BEGIN .entry-content-->
              <div class='webinar-content'>
              <p><span class='purple-text'>Event: </span>$temp_title</p>
              <p><span class='purple-text'>Speaker: </span>$temp_speaker</p>
              <a href='$temp_link' class='button-details'>View Event Details<span class='et-icon'></span></a>
              </div><!--END .entry-content-->
              </div><!--END .hentry-->
          </div></div>";
 } else {
    $output .= "not found.";
 }
 wp_reset_query();
 return $output;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a loop. Instead of `if ( $query->have_posts() ) {`, use:

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();

    // Rest of code

}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: That doesn't work. An if statement should be just fine, as in the standard documentation for WP_Query: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query. I am returning no events and I should be.

Comment: The loop will correctly set up the global `$post` - otherwise your `the_title` and `get_field` functions are operating on the post that contains the shortcode (the current post). Also, since you're querying multiple posts, I assumed you'd want to output for all of them, not just the first?

Comment: Right. Makes sense. I did get this to work a bit better via another method, however. It made better sense to use tribe_get_events() instead of the standard query. I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I did get this to work using tribe_get_events() instead, as below:

```
function webinar_list_shortcode($atts) {
  global $post;
 // Defaults
extract( shortcode_atts ( array (
        'numposts' => '5',
        'status' => 'upcoming',
        'eventcat' => ''
    ),
    $atts
));

$options = array(
    'eventDisplay'=>$status,
    'posts_per_page'=>$numposts,
    'tax_query'=> array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $eventcat
        )
    )
);

 // query is made
 $events = tribe_get_events( $options );

 // Reset and setup variables
 $output = '';
 $temp_title = '';
 $temp_link = '';
 $temp_ex = '';
 $temp_content = '';
 $temp_thumb = '';
 $temp_id = '';

 // the loop
foreach($events as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $temp_id = $post->ID;
    $temp_title = the_title('','',false);
    $temp_link = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $temp_content = get_the_content($post->ID);
    $temp_date = tribe_get_start_date( $post->ID, true, 'l, F j, Y' );
    $temp_speaker = get_field('speaker');
    //$temp_ex = get_the_excerpt();
      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $temp_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(200,200));
      } else {
        $temp_thumb = "";
      }

    // output all findings -
   $output .= "
  <div class='et_pb_row webinar-row clearfix'>
  <div class='et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4'>
   $temp_thumb
  </div>
  <div class='et_pb_column et_pb_column_3_4'>
   <div class='post-$temp_id' id='post-$temp_id'>
              <h3 class='webinar-time'>
                  $temp_date
              </h3><!--BEGIN .entry-content-->
              <div class='webinar-content'>
              <p><span class='purple-text'>Event: </span>$temp_title</p>
              <p><span class='purple-text'>Speaker: </span>$temp_speaker</p>
              <a href='$temp_link' class='button-details'>View Event Details<span class='et-icon'></span></a>
              </div><!--END .entry-content-->
              </div><!--END .hentry-->
          </div></div>";
 }
 wp_reset_query();
 return $output;
```

}